# Redirect IP to other IP

Tags: redirect, web-hosting, ipv4

Good Evening everybody!
we have moved our website onto another server. Previously it was hosted on AWS. Now we are having the issue that we do not have access to our DNS settings due to some maintenance works which take quite some time... But we do have access to our previously used IP address. And we know our new one. Is it possible to somehow forward the one IP to the other? So that it would look like:

Website visitor opens domain.com which is connected to the old IP 1.1.1.1 and this old IP which we have with AWS redirects it on to the new web space with IP 2.2.2.2?

I'm sorry if my explanation is not very clear but since I do not know how to approach this, it's hard to formulate the question :)

Regards

Comment: Redirection is a feature of the HTTP protocol that tells the browser to look the content from another address, causing the location on the address bar to change. That's probably not what you want. Therefore, configuring a _reverse proxy_ on the old address might solve your problem temporarily, until you can alter the DNS records.

Comment: You mean IP address. There are only two IPs: IPv4 and IPv6. IP means Internet Protocol. It sounds like you just need to change DNS to point to the new IP address.